# Can I data bind to a indexed property where a property of the parent is the index

Tags: wpf, binding

Using WPF with MVVM, my VM has an indexed property

```
IObject1 this[string key]
```

I need to bind a property of the view to a property of IObject1, and the key of the object1 that I need is the name of the control in the view.   Essentially I need nested bindings

```
<TextBlock x:Name="Key1"  Text="{Binding ["Key1"].DisplayText}
```

but, the name will very for different items so I need the nested binding

```
<TextBlock x:Name="Key1"  Text="{Binding [{Binding Name, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}].DisplayText}
```

My actual case is more complicated than this, but if I can get this far I think that I can figure out the rest.

I'm using Blend, and I'd love a way to teach my designer to do this type of thing within Blend, but I'm happy to use code if I need to.

Am I overlooking something obvious?  I can't figure out how to do this and I haven't stumbled upon the correct Google / Stack Overflow search term.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a weird solution lol, anyhose, you can solve it with MultiBinding & converters.

```
<TextBlock.Text>
<MultiBinding Converter={StaticResource combine}>
<Binding Path=Dictionary />
<Binding Path=Name />
</Multibinding>
```

Comment: Thanks.I think that will get me there.I'll let you know on Monday. My WPF education hasn't gotten to multibinding yet.